# How to remove a root CA certificate?

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, ssl-certificate, arch-linux

I am trying to delete a *root CA certificate*, but the `trust anchor --remove` command specified in the official [Red Hat 8 documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/security_hardening/using-shared-system-certificates_security-hardening) gives out a read-only error.

```
sudo trust anchor --remove --verbose "pkcs11:id=%c6%41%4f%df%64%5d%6c%2c%7b%ca%bc%bd%3e%b2%d4%85%cd%59%a7%49;type=cert"

(p11-kit:2482) remove_all: removing certificate: 19
p11-kit: couldn't remove read-only certificate
```

There is nothing in the documentation about this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I couldn't find any remakes in the documentation, too. However, it seems that the command `trust` treats certificates added manually to the [system-wide trust store](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/security_hardening/using-shared-system-certificates_security-hardening#the-system-wide-trust-store_using-shared-system-certificates) as *read-only certificates* and does not support the removal of these certificates.

The certificate you want to remove was probably copied manually or by a script into directory `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/` or `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/` (`/etc/ca-certificates/trust-source/` on Arch Linux). You can still remove it manually:

```sh
sudo rm /etc/ca-certificates/trust-source/example.pem
```

You need to run `update-ca-trust` afterwards to apply the changes:

```sh
sudo /usr/bin/update-ca-trust
# test if CA certificate is not trusted anymore:
curl -sv https://example.com
```

See the man page [update-ca-trust(8)](https://www.unix.com/man-page/centos/8/UPDATE-CA-TRUST/) for further information about the command.

This behavior is different from a certificate added via the `trust` command. These certificates have the extension `.p11-kit` in the system-wide trust store and also a different format than the imported PEM file:

```
# This file has been auto-generated and written by p11-kit. Changes will be
# unceremoniously overwritten.
[...]
[p11-kit-object-v1]
[...]
```

**Removing/Blacklisting Mozilla CA / nss-trust Certificates**

Removal/distrust of the Mozilla CA / nss-trust certificate authorities fail with the `trust` command, too (at least on Arch Linux):

```
$ sudo trust anchor --remove --verbose pkcs11:id=%C4%A7%B1%A4%7B%2C%71%FA%DB%E1%4B%90%75%FF%C4%15%60%85%89%10;type=cert
(p11-kit:10401) remove_all: removing certificate: 103
p11-kit: couldn't remove read-only certificate
(p11-kit:10401) remove_all: removing x-trust-assertion: 460
p11-kit: couldn't remove read-only x-trust-assertion
(p11-kit:10401) remove_all: removing nss-trust: 461
p11-kit: couldn't remove read-only nss-trust
p11-kit: 3 errors while processing
```

If you want distrust a certificate authority from this list, you can copy the certificate to the blacklist directory:

```sh
sudo cp /etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/cadir/DST_Root_CA_X3.pem /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/blacklist
# or on Arch Linux:
sudo cp /etc/ca-certificates/extracted/cadir/DST_Root_CA_X3.pem /etc/ca-certificates/trust-source/blacklist
# apply the changes:
sudo /usr/bin/update-ca-trust
```

In this example, *Let's Encrypt's* root CA is distrusted. You can test with `curl` if the blacklisting succeeded:

```sh
curl -sv https://serverfault.com
```

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault. Please keep coming back and giving high-quality answers like this one.

Comment: this doesnt work on centos 8.  do you know the solution which works on centos 8 ?

Comment: CentOS 8 is based on the sources of RHEL 8, so the instruction should apply to CentOS 8, too. Do you have some details what did not work?